# Javascript ELSE statement running regardless of IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

Very simple snippet of code (I'm new to programming), and I'm stumped.

Why is the console returning 0 for each iteration through the loop, regardless of whether the IF statement was true or not?

**For example, the IF statement runs, finds a match and writes 1 to the console, but then the ELSE statement runs too, resetting the variable "count".**

```js
//Snippet of the array of objects, that the program searches through
var students = [ 
  { 
    name: 'Dave',
    track: 'Front End Development',
    achievements: 158,
    points: 14730
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    track: 'Full Stack',
    achievements: '24',
    points: '2450'
  }
];

//Declaring variables
var message = '';
var student;
var count = 0;
var name;
var search;


while (true) {
 search = prompt("Enter a name to see their report, or type 'quit' to exit.");
 if (search.toUpperCase() == 'QUIT' || search.toUpperCase() == null) {
  console.log(8);
  break;
 }
 for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  student = students[i];
  name = search.toUpperCase();
  if (name == student.name.toUpperCase()) {
   count ++;
   console.log(count);
  } else {
   count = 0;
   console.log(count);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: you are always getting `false` for `name == student.name.toUpperCase()`. Please write full code so other can help you. and use `++count;` then `count++`

Comment: `name` or `student.name.toUpperCase()` one of these is returning a `false` value. hence console returning 0. debug your code thoroughly. Also initialise the `count` variable to 0 outside the `for loop`

Comment: What is the value of `students` and `name` variable?

Comment: Ive updated the code now @AnkitKathiriya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't immediately see the cause of your problem, the reset of `count = 0` in the `else` branch looks wrong and will cause problems if a name is repeated, but you should at least get `1` once on first match, whereas you assert that it always returns `0`.

Either way, a more idiomatic way of writing this would be:

```
var uSearch = search.toUpperCase();
var count = students.filter(function(student) {
    return student.name.toUpperCase() === uSearch;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `count = 0;` outside of the `for loop`. Just start with an empty counter.

Answer (score 0):

right, as Matt said...  you can initialize count=0 outside the loop first.  i would also ad a line `console.log(name)` after it's grabbed to debug before the condition.

```
count = 0
for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  student = students[i];
  name = search.toUpperCase();

  # show me the "name" before running condition
  console.log("name pulled from search: ",name)

  if (name == student.name.toUpperCase()) {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
  } else {
    count = 0;
    console.log(count);
  }
}
```

printing the `"name"` should give you an idea how the conditions matched.

Answer (score -1):

This is sample code for comparing value of two array .

```
   var count = 0;

var students = [
    { name:"string 1", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", value:"this", other: "that" }
];   

var search = [
    { name:"string 1", value:"this", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 3", value:"this", other: "that" }
]; 

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {

for (var j = 0; j < search.length; j++) {

    var student = students[i].name.toUpperCase();

  var names = search[j].name.toUpperCase();

  if (names == student) {
    count++;

    console.log(count);
  } else {
    count = 0;

    console.log(count);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `OP` used `student.name` presumably because the student is an object with a `name` property (alongside others) and not just a plain string.

Comment: @Alnitak now in this code take two object with three property in one array and comparing it  hopefully it clear .

Comment: And now you've introduced a double nested search - the OP only has _one_ search string.